# social sharing link on facebook always redirect to m.facebook on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, socialshare

I'm trying to do a url sharing via facebook, and somehow its always redirecting from

```
www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
```

to

```
wwww.m.facebook.com/sharer.php?
```

is this an often problem? is there a way around this?

ok url example:

i load this: [http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=%2430%20off%20%24599%20Appliances&p[summary]=Excludes%20Dacor%2C%20Jenn%20Air.%20See%20sales%20associate%20for%20details.%20Valid%20in-store%20and%20on-line.&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sears.com%2Fshc%2Fs%2Fdealscenter%3FstoreId%3D10153%26catalogId%3D12605%26langId%3D-1%26mv%3Dfacebook%26trackId%3D44867%26fromLandingPage%3Dtrue%26adCell%3DDC_membercoupons%26adCell%3DW2%26SID%3DISmxSFx00001%26couponTitle%3D%252430%2520off%2520%2524599%2520Appliances%26couponImage%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.shld.net%252F5172300%252Fue%252Fhome%252FS_HA_325x190.jpg%253Fwidth%253D100px%2526height%253D100px%26couponDesc%3D%252430%2520off%2520%2524599%2520AppliancesExcludes%2520Dacor%252C%2520Jenn%2520Air.%2520See%2520sales%2520associate%2520for%2520details.%2520Valid%2520in-store%2520and%2520on-line.&p[images][0]=https%3A%2F%2Fc.shld.net%2F5172300%2Fue%2Fhome%2FS_HA_325x190.jpg%3Fwidth%3D100px%26height%3D100px](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p%5btitle%5d=%2430%20off%20%24599%20Appliances&p%5bsummary%5d=Excludes%20Dacor%2C%20Jenn%20Air.%20See%20sales%20associate%20for%20details.%20Valid%20in-store%20and%20on-line.&p%5burl%5d=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sears.com%2Fshc%2Fs%2Fdealscenter%3FstoreId%3D10153%26catalogId%3D12605%26langId%3D-1%26mv%3Dfacebook%26trackId%3D44867%26fromLandingPage%3Dtrue%26adCell%3DDC_membercoupons%26adCell%3DW2%26SID%3DISmxSFx00001%26couponTitle%3D%252430%2520off%2520%2524599%2520Appliances%26couponImage%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.shld.net%252F5172300%252Fue%252Fhome%252FS_HA_325x190.jpg%253Fwidth%253D100px%2526height%253D100px%26couponDesc%3D%252430%2520off%2520%2524599%2520AppliancesExcludes%2520Dacor%252C%2520Jenn%2520Air.%2520See%2520sales%2520associate%2520for%2520details.%2520Valid%2520in-store%2520and%2520on-line.&p%5bimages%5d%5b0%5d=https%3A%2F%2Fc.shld.net%2F5172300%2Fue%2Fhome%2FS_HA_325x190.jpg%3Fwidth%3D100px%26height%3D100px)

which redirects to this

https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=%2430+off+%24599+Appliances&p%5Bsummary%5D=Excludes+Dacor%2C+Jenn+Air.+See+sales+associate+for+details.+Valid+in-store+and+on-line.&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sears.com%2Fshc%2Fs%2Fdealscenter%3FstoreId%3D10153%26catalogId%3D12605%26langId%3D-1%26mv%3Dfacebook%26trackId%3D44867%26fromLandingPage%3Dtrue%26adCell%3DDC_membercoupons%26adCell%3DW2%26SID%3DISmxSFx00001%26couponTitle%3D%252430%2520off%2520%2524599%2520Appliances%26couponImage%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fc.shld.net%252F5172300%252Fue%252Fhome%252FS_HA_325x190.jpg%253Fwidth%253D100px%2526height%253D100px%26couponDesc%3D%252430%2520off%2520%2524599%2520AppliancesExcludes%2520Dacor%252C%2520Jenn%2520Air.%2520See%2520sales%2520associate%2520for%2520details.%2520Valid%2520in-store%2520and%2520on-line.&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fc.shld.net%2F5172300%2Fue%2Fhome%2FS_HA_325x190.jpg%3Fwidth%3D100px%26height%3D100px&_rdr

and firs tlink shares, second dont. asks share on your time line with a http:// box.

Comment: Can you provide a full url, and the useragent you're seeing this with?

Comment: i could but honestly it's not any different from jus tloading the above url in your phone and observe the redirection.

Comment: I'm being redirected to 'm.facebook.com/sharer.php?', which is a perfectly functional, mobile adapted dialog. Without more information, there's nothing actionable here.

Comment: @SeanKinsey code edited, the two links clearly do not work the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on Facebook's end - try reporting it through developers.facebook.com/bugs.